# Editing bounds to get rid of white-space within a plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, whitespace

[image]![Left: Data from 2000-2040, Right: Data from 2001-2039][2]

Is there a way I can manually edit the bounds of my plot? When my x axis data runs from 2000 to 2040 matplotlib rearranges the plot such that a lot of white-space is produced on both the left and right sides of the plot, as in the left picture. However when I change my x axis data from 2001 to 2039 there is no whitespace as in the right picture. I suspect this happens because of how matplotlib automatically arranges the ticks. The question is how can the x-ticks be manipulated manually to avoid unnecessary whitespace? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the various pyplot functions called `xlim`, `ylim` (to set the limits of the axes), `xticks`, `yticks` (to set the tick positions) etc.  Read [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html).

Comment: Thanks for putting me on track, I have found what I want now: 

ax.set_xbound(xmin,xmax)