# matplotlib.pyplot.imshow: removing white space within plots when using attributes "sharex" and "sharey"

Tags: python, matplotlib, whitespace

I have a problem which is similar to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120749/matplotlib-limits-when-using-plot-and-imshow-in-same-axes).  The difference is that I get unwanted white spaces inside the plot area when I plot two subplots which share axes via the `sharex` and `sharey` attributes.  The white spaces persist even after setting `autoscale(False)`.  For example, using similar code as in the answer to the post mentioned above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
ax.autoscale(False)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex=ax, sharey=ax)   # adding sharex and sharey
ax2.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
ax2.autoscale(False)
plt.show()
```

results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBoWo.png) image.

I have also tried `ax.set_xlim(0, 10)` and `ax.set_xbound(0, 10)` as per suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851410/editing-bounds-to-get-rid-of-white-space-within-a-plot-in-matplotlib), but to no avail.  How can I get rid of the extra white spaces?    Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1789#issuecomment-14203547), adding:

```
ax.set_adjustable('box-forced')
ax2.set_adjustable('box-forced')
```

solves the problem.

([documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect))

Comment: This is helpful, but I would add another way, if you don't mind losing the aspect ratio and want to fill all the available axes space: use `aspect='auto'` in `imshow()`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `plt.subplots` as:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=False)
ax[0].imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
ax[0].autoscale(False)
ax[1].imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
ax[1].autoscale(False)
```

I get [image: this figure] with no white spaces within axes. 
Using `figsize` within `plt.subplots` or `fig.subplots_adjust` you can get better axis ratios.

Comment: Thanks.  However, I would like a solution where the axes' ranges do not change with resizing of the figure.

Comment: @mlynn: what do you mean? do you want your axes to be always the same absolute size (like 5x5 cm)? or you want them to maintain the same aspect ratio independently of the figure size?

Comment: What I would like is for each subplot to display the full dimensions of the image (in this case, 10x10 pixels), maintaining the same aspect ratio independently of the figure size.  Basically, if I do not add the `sharex` and `sharey` options in my original code above, I get the plots I want.  I can resize the figure, and each subplot would resize accordingly.  The reason I would like the axes to be shared is that when I zoom in on one subplot, I would like the other subplot to zoom in correspondingly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the helpful machinery from using `add_subplot`.  Notice that the amount of white space changes if you resize the figure.

The following seems to work (until you re-size the figure)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = fig.add_axes([.3, .55, .35, .35]) 
ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
ax.autoscale(False)
ax2 = fig.add_axes([.3,  .05, .35, .35], sharex=ax, sharey=ax ) 
ax2.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
ax2.autoscale(False)

plt.show()
```

This looks like a bad interaction between the size/location of the `axes` object, the shared axes, and the equal aspect ratio from `imshow`.

If you can live with out the ticks, you can do

```
ax.set_axis_off()
ax2.set_axis_off()
```

I think it is worth opening an issue on the matplotlib github for this.

Comment: Setting `aspect=auto` would get rid of the white spaces in this case, but this is not always ideal.  I opened an issue on the matplotlib github as you suggested -- thanks.