# matplotlib.pyplot.imshow: removing white space/margins

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, whitespace

I would like to use `plt.imshow` without a large white margin around the image. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(8, 8)
plt.imshow(data, origin='lower', interpolation='None', aspect='equal')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

and viewer window produced:

[image]

How to reduce the white space margin around the image?

This is not the same question as [matplotlib.pyplot.imshow: removing white space within plots when using attributes "sharex" and "sharey"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077364/matplotlib-pyplot-imshow-removing-white-space-within-plots-when-using-attribute). I tried suggestions from there to no effect.

Comment: `plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)`.  See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837979/removing-white-space-around-a-saved-image)

Comment: @JohanC Great! This actually fills all available window pane. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using [matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) may solve your problem.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(8, 8)
plt.imshow(data, origin='lower', interpolation='None', aspect='equal')
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: tight layout exemple]

Comment: Thank you, it works nicely. The comment above with `plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)` fills the window even better.

Comment: The command given by @PaulJurczak is the actual solution. I was able to get rid of white background only with this command. Thank you very much!